# Верстка и Internet Explorer, решение проблем для IE

Tags: css, вёрстка, internet-explorer

Верстка сайта, в период его разработки, велась с браузером Chrome. Firefox и Opera, так же успешно отобразили сайт. И тут настал час Х, я взял свой последний обновленный IE 9, и то, что появилось на экране, я вообще не ожидал увидеть. Верстки будто бы нет вообще. Все просто развалилось на куски. До свидания css, IE тебя не понимает. Но ведь нужно что-то делать, нужно доработать шаблон таким образом, чтобы IE смог его нормально показать.

Я вот даже не знаю с чего начать. Подскажите, для начала, как увидеть на чем именно IE ломается?

Comment: Плагин html validator это отличный вариант, может кто и будь подскажет такой плагин для IE?

Comment: Грац, нашел в сети онлайн валидатор по соглашению W3C http://validator.w3.org/
Выдал мне : 34 Errors, 1 warning(s)
И подробно рассказал что и где в коде 8))

Answer (score 0):

В верстке особо не силен, но поставь себе хотя бы `html validator` - плагин для `firefox`, на нем можно посмотреть все ошибки в `html` разметке, `div` не закрыл или еще чего.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотреть можно если всем элементам через `CSS` поставить `border`. Но лучше ставить его тем блокам которые уезжают, чтобы посмотреть, почему пошел сдвиг.

Answer (score 0):

Установите себе на период верстки [firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). Как поправите, удалите его.

Answer (score 0):

Если отвалилось всё, то скорее всего IE испольует quirks-режим, который по сути является эмуляцией IE 5.5. Проверить можно через `document.documentMode`. Скорее всего это вызвано отсутствием doctype'а или присутствием перед ним чего-либо, в том числе пробелов, комментариев или BOM. Вот на BOM стоит особенно проверить, потому что он невидимый.